# Creating and assigning values to deeply nested objects

Tags: javascript

```
var obj={
    one:{
        two:{
            three:{
            }
        }
    }
};

function test(){
obj.one=1;
obj.one.two=2;
obj.one.two.three=3;

alert(obj.one);
alert(obj.one.two);
alert(obj.one.two.three);
}
```

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong and give me a corrected example to go by?

Comment: Could someone explain what the question is? In other words, you need to explain what's happening compared to what you're expecting.

Comment: Attempting to setup a collection of variables which can be accessed using dot notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes more sense and works this way:

```
var obj={
    one:{value:1,
         two:{value:2,
              three:{value:3}
        }
    }
};

function test(){
obj.one.value=1;
obj.one.two.value=2;
obj.one.two.three.value=3;

alert(obj.one.value);
alert(obj.one.two.value);
alert(obj.one.two.three.value);
}
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fqKg2/)

#### Why doesn't your code work?

Doing this:

```
obj.one = 1;//works till here
obj.one.two = 2;//doesn't work. 
//>> obj.one is "1" and doesn't have any "two" property
obj.one.two.three = 3;//same thing. "two" doesn't exist anyway. 
//Neither does "three"
```

Comment: It needs something to hold the variable otherwise the object gets wiped!  Got it!

Comment: @Hawk Yup. I included a _better_ solution, or one that might work for you :)

Comment: @Hawk you're welcome :) Consider accepting some answers to your posts. [See how accepting works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Completely missed that!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

In the first line of `test()` function, you are changing the value of `obj.one` from an object to an integer.

Comment: I see now.  Is there a way to do this at all?

Comment: @Hawk Yes; don't over-write the object at `obj.one` -- set a property on it.

Answer (score 2):

You wipe out the "deeply nested objects" when you set `obj.one` to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put properties in number values, since they aren't objects.